# Click to Call refuse to work on IOS flutter

Tags: ios, flutter

The call button refuse to navigate to dialpad on ios but it worked on android on flutter.

Here's the code I implemented, but still not working on IOS

```
Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
    margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
    child: Row(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
            child: Text(
            '${_con.restaurant.phone} \n${_con.restaurant.mobile}',
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
            ),
        ),
        SizedBox(width: 10),
        SizedBox(
            width: 42,
            height: 42,
            child: FlatButton(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
            onPressed: () {
                launch("tel:${_con.restaurant.mobile}");
            },
            child: Icon(
                Cretello_app.contact2,
                color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
                size: 24,
            ),
            color: Theme.of(context).accentColor.withOpacity(0.9),
            shape: StadiumBorder(),
            ),
        ),
        ],
    ),
),
```

[image: Here is an image of what it looks like]

Comment: Do you get an error or nothing happens? Are you testing in a real device?

Comment: @ClaudioRedi Nothing Happens and I'm testing it in a real device.

Comment: Can you post the number so we can see how it looks like?

Comment: @JideGuru I used a Random Number just for testing. Here is the number; 1-568-737-4403